# How do you change Ubuntu 21.04 lock screen image?

Tags: gnome, themes, gdm

After searching, I couldn't figure out how to **effectively** change the lock screen image.

From the search results I have found, I think that I have to extract the `.gresource` from `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` edit the `lockDialogGroup ID` in extracted file `gdm3.css` and then recompile.

Here's where I encountered the problem; I couldn't figure out how to get the `XML` file needed to recompile the `.gresource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the lock screen image, you'll need to have the `libglib2.0-dev` package installed and you'll likely also want to take a look at [the work Pratap Kumar has already done](https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3/blob/TrailRun/focalgdm3) to do this for Ubuntu 20.04. The bits you'll be interested in are down near the end of the file.

---

**Note:** Pratap's solution *says* it will only work on 20.04 but it does work just fine with 21.04 if you change this line:

```
if [ "$codename" == "focal" ] && [ "$osname" == '"Ubuntu"' ]
```

To this:

```
if [ "$codename" == "focal" ] || [ "$codename" == "groovy" ] || [ "$codename" == "hirsute" ]
```

Then you can more easily update your background [following these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1359611/1222991)

Comment: Wow didn't think that this solution could work, my actual thought was "if it was an XML for 20.04, there could be some chances that it wont work in 21.04. Dont risk." Thanks a lot!!